# Autobahn Server connection loss issue

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I am using Autobahn library for web socket connection. My backend server is php.

I am facing **WebSockets connection lost** issue very frequently when i have started socket connection.

How to overcome this issue? Is there any way to connect to socket again without informing user.

Comment: please specify yours question with a better description

Comment: I have elaborate my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no auto reconnect option for Autobahn Android, you need to manually open a new connection in the `onClose` callback on the client.

UPDATE:
Looking through the Autobahn code on github I noticed the [WebSocketConnection#reconnect()](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketConnection.java#L304) method, seems to be included in releases 0.5.1 and 0.5.2, but it is not documented in the API documentation on the Autobahn website.

Comment: Should i make WebSocketConnection's new obj or just need to call mConnection.connect?

Comment: @Dhrupal you should make new object. But see my updated answer for alternative